# Proof that $A$ and $B$ nonempty and closed in $\Bbb C$ means that $A\cup B$ is closed in $\Bbb C$ verification

Tags: general-topology

> Is the below proof rigorous?

---

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty and closed in $\Bbb C$.

Assume $A\cup B$ is not open, then there is a limit point $p$, not in $A\cup B$, that must be in $\overline{A}$ or $\overline{B}$, which means that

$$p\in\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$$, but $A$ and $B$ are closed and hence $A=\overline{A}$ and $B=\overline{B}$ and thus $p\in\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}=A\cup B$

contradiction, hence $A\cup B$ is closed.

---

Attempt 2:

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty and closed in $\Bbb C$.

$p\in (A\cup B)'$ means that $p\in A\cup B$

Note for duplicate thing: That's countably infinite, mine is two, and that is false, mine is true, that's for topology mines without

Comment: Yes, you need to further justify that line. Also, just as a point of style, your proof doesn't really need the contradiction. You never needed to assume $p \notin A \cup B$, as you end up proving directly that $p \in A \cup B$.

Comment: @Jhance E.g. Say I have taken an arbitrary $p$ and then show that this $p$ must fall into the set?

Comment: You take an arbitrary limit point of $A \cup B$ and show it fall in $A \cup B$, no need to assume it doesn't fall in $A \cup B$. Also, the new line of reasoning is just becoming circular. Ultimately you need to write out what it means to be a limit point and show that a limit point of $A \cup B$ falls into one of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Lemma 1 $(A\cup B)' = A'\cup B'$

Lemma 2 $p\in \overline{A\cup B}\implies p \in \overline A \cup \overline B$

and then my last line of the original proof is rigorous I think

Comment: That claim is false. Consider two discs that partially overlap, the correct claim is that $(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cup B'$. Again, I don't think this actually helps, as this is just restating your unecessary assumption that $p \notin A \cup B$.

Comment: @Jhance Okay I will try again

Comment: I have to leave now, but as one last comment: I think you are too eager to try and do everything without mentioning a convergent sequence. If $p$ is a limit point of $A \cup B$ then there is a sequence of elements of $A \cup B$ converging to it.

Comment: 1) The label for complex analysis is inappropriate. 2) You don't need to talk about limits.

Comment: @Squirtle But the proof on proof wiki uses the definition of a topology, I don't know any topology as of yet

Comment: @Squirtle That's countably infinite, mine is two, and that is false, mine is true, that's for topology mines without

Comment: Topology ..... is unavoidable.  Don't resist it.  It might sound like a funny word, but its really not scary.  And I marked it duplicate because you are aware of the wikiproof proof and you should just try to understand that.

Comment: @Squirtle But if I invoke that defintion of a topology thing, I will probably need to prove it

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107692/prove-that-a-finite-union-of-closed-sets-is-also-closed

Comment: You might prefer Michael Greinecker's answer

Comment: @Squirtle Yes that was very helpful. Thank you!