# Prove by induction on the number of points (the cardinality) in $F$ that $F$ is closed.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cardinals

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $F \subseteq X$ be a finite set. Prove that $F$ is closed.

Proof. Suppose $(a_n)$ is convergent in $F$. Because every convergent sequence in a finite metric space is eventually constant, then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \ge N$, we have $a_n=a_N \in F$. As $a_N \in F$, then $(a_n) \to a_N \in F$. Thus $lim_{a_n} \in F$, and hence $F$ is closed.

Is this correct?

And now I would like to prove this by induction on the number of points (the cardinality) in $F$.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $F \subseteq X$ be a finite set. Prove (by induction on the cardinality of $F$) that $F$ is closed.

What I've done so far:

Proof. Base case: If $F=\emptyset$. Then the claim is vacuously true since $\emptyset$ does not contain any sequence $(a_n)$. In other words, the assertion is false; and therefore, the implication that $lim_{a_n} \in \emptyset$ is true.

Assume that for some natural number $n \ge 0$ that $|F|=n \Rightarrow F$ is closed. Since $F$ is closed, then $(a_n) \in F$ such that $(a_n) \to x$, where $x \in F$.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an approach using sequences, it would be easier if we used the fact that [finite union of closed sets is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107692/prove-that-a-finite-union-of-closed-sets-is-also-closed?rq=1).

Comment: But how does that use the number of points (the cardinality) in $F$?

Comment: A set of $n+1$ points can be written as the disjoint union of a set with $n$ points and a singleton set. If both of them are closed, then their union is closed as well. We use the induction hypothesis to get that the $n$ point set is closed.